# TinyMCE: loading an external plugin into Angular CLI based web app

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce, angular-cli

*Please find a full repro project here*: https://github.com/Myrmex/tinymce-plugin-repro.

*Solution found*: see at the bottom.

I'm developing an Angular4 web app using TinyMCE with a very simple custom plugin of mine. This plugin, named `format-display`, has the purpose of showing the color of the text under the cursor, mapped to some underlying meaning (e.g. red means something, green something else, etc.). The plugin just reads the color under the cursor and displays it with its mapping, if any. It works fine in its build environment (built in Typescript with the Yeoman generator from https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/yeoman-generator/): my issue is that it's not loaded when used in my Angular app.

This being a custom plugin (not packed in the TinyMCE package), I must add it to the editor using `external_plugins` rather than `plugins` when initializing it, and copy the dist folder (`dist/format-display`) under `assets/plugins` (or elsewhere, always under `assets`). As for any 3rd party non-NPM like library, I then add the plugin source code in `angular-cli.json` under `scripts`.

The TinyMCE plugin manager seems to correctly register my external plugin, as I can see it in `tinymce.pluginmanager` during debug, and the registration code is invoked with no errors. Yet, the editor does not seem to load my registered plugin: no part of its code ever gets called.

Inspecting my sources during debug I could find two instances of my plugin.js:

- webpack:///./src/assets/plugins/format-display/plugin.js
- localhost:4200/assets/plugins/format-display/plugin.js

I assume the first comes from including the plugin code in `angular-cli.json` under `scripts`, and the second from the `external_plugins` property when the editor is initialized. Yet, if I remove the reference from angular-cli nothing seems to change, and the plugin still does not get loaded.

**Addition**: I must add that this duplication does not seem to have side effects. I tried to change my generated plugin.js code into `var plugin_1 = __webpack_require__(0); if (!tinymce.PluginManager.lookup.formatDisplay) { tinymce.PluginManager.add('formatDisplay', plugin_1["default"]); }`, but the problem persists, even if now when I inspect `tinymce.PluginManager.lookup` I can see the expected 2 instances: one for `fullscreen`, another one (no more 2 instances) for `formatDisplay`.

I followed these directions for TinyMCE with Angular, but they do not cover the case of an external plugin, and I'm a TinyMCE newcomer:

- https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/
- https://www.ephox.com/blog/angular-2-and-tinymce/?_ga=1.117951882.2068174515.1491150296

**Solution**

I found out how to make it work. The repro project has been updated accordingly. To sum up: despite the official documentation (as far as I can tell), I must NOT load via `external_plugins`, but let Webpack load and just list the desired plugin in the `plugins` property. Also, there I must use the camel-cased identifier, thus `formatDisplay` and not `format-display`, like:

```
  tinymce.init({
  ...
  plugins: ['fullscreen', 'formatDisplay'],
```

Comment: I couldn't make your solution work, but [this one](https://github.com/wiris/mathtype-integration-js-dev/blob/stable/doc/frameworks/AngularJS/tinymce/tinymce5.md) helped me a lot. Also your docs links are broken, [this is the new one](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/#tinymceangularintegrationquickstartguide)